# How Single VM in a availability set differs from VM not in any availability set?

Tags: azure

What is the difference between putting `only one vm` in availability set vs not putting the vm into any availability set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between putting one vm in availability set vs
>   not putting the vm into any availability set?

If only on VM in that availability set, there is no SLA for this VM, same as single VM without availability set.

I think the only difference it that, when this VM in availability set, we can create a new VM in this availability set to get HA. But a single VM without availability set, we can't add this VM to one availability set, if we want to add this VM to one availability set, we need recreate it(ARM).

In ASM(classic mode), we can add one VM to the availability set.

Comment: Consider upvoting question ;-)

Comment: Worth mentioning that as of March 2018, a single VM in an availability set is covered by a 99.9% SLA when it is using premium storage. This was changed in v1.7 of the Virtual Machines SLA.

Comment: Last edited, 4 minutes ago. Make edits, save...edits can only be made for 5 minutes... Honestly.
From version 1.8 (March 2018) VM SLA:
"Single Instance" is defined as any single Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine that either is not deployed in an Availability Set or has only one instance deployed in an Availability Set.
For any Single Instance Virtual Machine using premium storage for all Operating System Disks and Data Disks, we guarantee you will have Virtual Machine Connectivity of at least 99.9%.

Comment: Azure moves like lightning sometimes so answering questions in SO becomes risky since you'll be wrong in no time! :)

Answer (score 0):

An availability set is designed to operate under a load balancer or an application gateway that distribute traffic among VMs. This helps to achieve high(er) availability (HA) than just a VM on its own (in case a VM goes offline or becomes unhealthy), or to distribute traffic for intensive applications by sharing the load across 2 or more machines. An Availability Set will also come with probes to detect unhealthy VM instances.

However, when you're dealing with one VM, are availability sets worth setting up? Short answer is no, unless you want to leverage the benefits of an application gateway which include: filtering & firewall, application level attacks and layer 7 benefits like SSL and session management.

If you're creating availability sets using ARM code for quick deployment (e.g if you had a production environment with multiple VMs), it does however make sense to deploy Availability Sets with one VM if you're repeating the same setup for test environments e.g. Dev and Staging environments may only use one VM within an availability set simply to preserve the same gateway architecture as your production environment.

Disadvantages of Availability Sets include not being able to easily restore to a VM backup into an availability set, as this feature does yet have a GUI. Restoring a VM on its own, much easier. And they involve a bit more architectural setup/design which is harder to replicate if you're not usimg ARM templates (code deployments).